# Fetch the record from multiple records based on string column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as follows:

[image: Employee_Activity_Table]
I need to create a query so that I can get the below result (only the highlighted records):

[image: ResultRequired]
I have tried using something like below but still getting all the records and not only the highlighted ones.

```
Select  EmpPk as [User EmpPK],
Activity_PK  as [Activity PK],
Attempt_Start_Date as [Attempt Start Date],
Attempt_Completion_Date as  [Attempt Completion Date],
Registration_Status as  [Registration Status],
Attendance_Status as    [Attendance Status],
EstCrdHrs 
From Employee_Activity                          
Where   ((Attendance_Status='In Progress' AND Registration_Status ='In Progress') 
OR (Attendance_Status='Attended' AND Registration_Status ='Completed'))
```

Comment: Please describe precisely the logic that you are looking to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You did not precisely describe the logic that you are looking to implement.

I understand that, for each `EmpPk`, you want records where `attendance_status = 'Attended' and registration_status = 'Completed'`; if there is no such record, then you want all other records.

If so, you could phrase this with `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from employee_activity ea
where 
    (
        ea.attendance_status = 'Attended' 
        and ea.registration_status = 'Completed'
    ) or not exists (
        select 1 
        from employee_activity ea1 
        where 
            ea1.empPk = ea.empPk 
            and ea1.attendance_status = 'Attended' 
            and ea1.registration_status = 'Completed'
    )
```

You could also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(
            partition by empPk 
            order by case when attendance_status = 'Attended' and registration_status = 'Completed' then 1 else 2 end
        ) rn
    from employee_activity
) t
where rn = 1
```

The `order by` clause of window function `rank()` puts the "completed" record of each employee first; then the outer query filter on top ranked record(s) per employee (if there is no "complete" record, then all other records of the same customer will be ranked first).